# Regex: составление запроса

Tags: java, регулярные-выражения

Пожалуйста, помогите составить регулярное выражение, которое будет матчить такой текст:

```
<AddedAttachment>
    235235e8f8567e587f658o7f658e/6fw/e8o56/e8o65/e8o6c/5e6c8o5ev5
</AddedAttachment>
```

Нужно именно выделить весь текст (он может быть любой), который будет содержаться между двумя тегами `<AddedAttachment>`, включая эти теги. Например, в выражении

```
<Object>
    <AddedAttachment>
        235235e8f8567e587f658o7f658e/6fw/e8o56/e8o65/e8o6c/5e6c8o5ev5
    </AddedAttachment>
</Object>
```

регулярка должна заматчить именно

```
    <AddedAttachment>
        235235e8f8567e587f658o7f658e/6fw/e8o56/e8o65/e8o6c/5e6c8o5ev5
    </AddedAttachment>
```

Comment: Ну так и пишите прямо влоб... `.*(<AddedAttachment>\X*<\/AddedAttachment>).*`

Comment: @Akina 1. Зачем `.*` по краям? 2. Что такое `\X`?

Comment: @Qwertiy 1. Привычка... да, наверное, лишнее. 2. Любой символ, включая newline, вроде бы...

Comment: @Akina `\X` не поддерживается в регулярных выражениях Java. `\P{M}\p{M}*+` - вот его эквивалент. Но я бы просто использовал `.` c `Pattern.DOTALL`.

Comment: Используйте корректный инструмент, а не *шутка про регулярные выражения*. В данном случае XPath.

Answer (score -1):

```
<AddedAttachment>((?!</AddedAttachment>)[\s\S])*</AddedAttachment>
```

Comment: Использование конструкции "tempered greedy token" в данном случае неоправдано, это решение очень неэффективно и при работе с более длинными совпадениями в Java может вызвать ошибку переполнения стека. Кроме того, `[\s\S]` не нужен, так как в Java `.` может находить переходы на новую строку, если добавить опцию `Pattern.DOTALL` - и это работает быстрее.